# can anyone tell me what is the main difference between @using and @Model in Mvc in view ,what is required when

Tags: asp.net

I am new to Asp.Net and MVC as such . The one thing that keeps confusing me is that we use @Using and @Model in our views sometimes , i need more clarity on what is required when and why.

Comment: google is your friend and any Razor tutorial

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`@using` is the same as as the [the using directive](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx) in normal C# code: it gives access to Types of a Namespace without having to explicitly stating it.

`@model` defines the type of the Model for the view (or partial), allowing typed access to it and it's members.

`@Model`accesses the model linked with this view in the current call, as in the actual Data.

Comment: i m able to access the model properties(names) by using both /@Model.Name and Model.Name.. Why it is so. I got that "Model" is the variable declared to access the actual model but why does it works even with

Answer (score 3):

The `@using` is used to designate blocks of code that have objects which implement the `IDisposable` interface, but it can also be used with HTML helpers in ASP.NET MVC, like this:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm()) {
    // Do stuff in the form here
}
```

This is equivalent to:

```
@{ Html.BeginForm(); }
    // Do stuff in the form here
@{ Html.EndForm(); }
```

So, in this case, the `@using` will render the closing tag of the form for you.

The `@model` (notice the lowercase `m`) is used to declare the strong type the model is for the view, like this:

```
@model YourNamespace.YourTypeName
```

Then in your actual markup, you reference the model using the `Model` keyword (notice the uppercase 'M`), like this:

```
@Model.SomePropertyInYourModel
```

Comment: Thank you lots Karl Was Very Helpful .!!

Comment: @JitheshChandra - no problem, if you feel the answer helped you, then accept and/or up-vote the answer. :-)

Comment: @KarlAnderson, it even works with Model.SomePropertyInYourModel, why we need to use the symbole "@" in the front?

Comment: @TechQuery - if you are already inside of a code block (`{` and `}`), then you don't need the `@` symbol.